# Not able to append data to Div and redirect page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have a default page with list of items. When I click on those Items I need to dynamically append data to div in Page B and redirect the app to Page B.

I added this div in PageB
''

On Click event I am doing following action in .js file:

```
'$(document).on('click', '#selectConcept', function (node) {
    var ncid = this.textContent.slice(6,25);
    $.ajax({

        dataType: "json",

        url: "http://txv-trmindexer01:8080/CommonTerminologyLeopardSearch/rest/getConceptByNcid/" + ncid,

        error: function () {
            alert("ERROR");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.href = 'getfacets.html';
            for (var result = 0; result < finalSearchResults.length; result++) {
                if (finalSearchResults[result].ncid == ncid) {

                    $("#selectedConceptitem").empty();
                    var selectedconcept = "<p>" + "ncid: " + finalSearchResults[result].ncid + "," + "cid: " + finalSearchResults[result].cid + "</p>";

                    $(selectedconcept).appendTo("#selectedConceptitem");


                }
            }

        }    });
});'
```

I am able to redirect page, but nothing is appended to Div.

Can anyone help me out with this..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but I guess the code runs before the new page is loaded. So you could try to wrap the code in a function run at `onload` event time

```js
window.location.href = 'getfacets.html';
window.onload = function() {
    for (var result = 0; result < finalSearchResults.length; result++) {
        if (finalSearchResults[result].ncid == ncid) {
            $("#selectedConceptitem").empty();
            var selectedconcept = "<p>" + "ncid: " + finalSearchResults[result].ncid + "," + "cid: " + finalSearchResults[result].cid + "</p>";
            $(selectedconcept).appendTo("#selectedConceptitem");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:**

As soon as you set "window.location.href" property the page navigates to your page B and you loose your fetched data.

**You have two solutions to the problem:**

1. Use Single Page Application (SPA) application approach wherein you could create a new global scope for your fetched data, which can now be used by page B
2. Send the ncID as a querystring parameter to page B and and implement the service call and data appending logic on page B